# 401 ERROR with API sending blank basic auth

Tags: reactjs, api, flask

I am creating an API to send a basic auth login request to my flask backend, however when sending a request I get

```
{username: "ww", password: "ww"}
POST http://localhost:5000/login 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)
```

i have logged the data entered to check is was being set, this response is returned via the js console on the browser, the logging in my flask console is as follows :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2019 16:21:07] "OPTIONS /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'username': '', 'password': ''}
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2019 16:21:07] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 401 -
```

My flask login route looks like

```
@app.route('/login', methods =['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth = request.authorization
        print(auth)
        if not auth.username or not auth.password:
            return make_response('Could not verify :(', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

        user = User.query.filter_by(username = auth.username).first()

        if not user:
            return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

        if check_password_hash(user.password, auth.password):
            token = jwt.encode({'public_id' : user.public_id, 'exp' : datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30) }, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
            return jsonify({'token' : token.decode('UTF-8')})
        return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})
```

this is the login component on my react front end
export class Login extends React.Component {

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
        }
    }
    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    submitHandler = e => {
        const headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        }
        var username = this.username
        var password = this.password
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state)
        axois.post('http://localhost:5000/login',this.state,{ 
        headers: {
            headers
        }            
        ,auth: {
            username : username,
            password: password
        }
        })
        .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
        .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }          

    render() {
        const {username, password} = this.state

        return <div className = "base-container" ref={this.props.containerRef}>
            <div className="content">
              <div className="logo">
                <img src={Logo} alt="Logo"/>
              </div>
              <form className="form" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="username"> Username</label>
                      <input type="text" 
                      name="username" 
                      value ={username} 
                      placeholder="Username"
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="password"> Password</label>
                      <input type="password" 
                      name="password" 
                      value={password} 
                      placeholder="Password"
                      onChange ={this.changeHandler}/>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" className="btn">Login</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div className="footer">

            </div>
        </div>

    }
}
```

My request works through using postman so im unsure why it doesnt using React? I am using Flask-Cors to prevent CORS errors and storing the user data in auth header so im not sure why flask cant read it.

I am very new to this so any help would be great :) Thanks !

Comment: You are sending username and password as request body with POST and in your route handler, you are trying to access username and password from the authorization header

Comment: its in the header under auth aswell ? if i remove it i get a CORS error